# How to secure jhipster-registry and how to aggregate api-docs inside of jhipster apigateway when profile prod is active

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have been fidgeting with jhipster lately and been out of touch from the spring ecosystem so it's making some of the navigation hard.

Running `jhipster 8.1.0` and all microservices are generated with jhipster with micro frontend and reactive, i.e the apigateway and the other services. I am using the registry from docherhub:jhipster/jhipster-registry and using docker-compose for the deployment to simulate production deployment. All the microservices are deployed with the java properties -Dspring.cloud.config.profile=prod,api-docs for prod and api-docs profiles.

I have the following:

- configserver for all the configuration (native)
- jhispter-registry for discovery only
- apigateway
- serviceA
- serviceB

1. All the services have registered with the jhipster-registry but only apigateway and jhipster-registry show up on the swagger-ui. Though when I run on my IDE all the other swagger apis aggregate nicely. Not sure which properties of the `application-dev.yml` I must use to enable it. I have not seen any configuration of `spring.cloud.gateway.routes` nowhere.

> I have also seen this `These can be used along with both the dev and prod profiles. Please note that by default, the api-docs profile is not enabled in prod and enabled in dev by setting the spring.profiles.group.dev profile group property in application.yml.`

in the documentation at https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/ but not too sure how to use it.

2. I have also passed the environment `- JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}` to the jhipster-registry but it's still using admin/admin

Grateful if you can point me to the right direction for the 2 questions. Been banging my head for 2 days straight now.